# How to fix GTK+ 3 applications' menu in Ubuntu GNOME?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, gnome-tweak-tool

I'm using Ubuntu GNOME 15.10.

There is a problem - when I turn off the top bar application's menu in GNOME Tweak Tool, instead of standard gnome behavior I get some broken stuff.

I have added the GNOME3 Staging PPA, but it also has the same issue.

How can I fix this?

[image: How it looks]